# How to write the solution set of an augmented matrix in reduced-row echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am new here, so please excuse me if my question is not on par with the guidelines (which I have read).

**Introduction**

I am used to having one variable in the tuple, e.g.:

$$
\begin{array}{rcrcrcr}
x &  &  & + & \frac{3}{5}z & = & 1\\
 &  & y & - & \frac{2}{5}z & = & -1\\
 &  & &  & 0 & = & 0
\end{array}
$$

Would have the solution set as a set of tuples:

$$
S=\left\{ \left(1-\frac{3}{5}z,-1+\frac{2}{5}z,z\right)\mid z\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
$$

And a solution set as a set of vectors:

$$
S=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{3}{5}\\
\frac{2}{5}\\
1
\end{pmatrix}z\mid z\in\mathbb{R}\right\} 
$$

**My Question**

Say I start with this simple linear system:

$$
\begin{array}{rcrcrcr}
x & + & y & - & z & = & 3\\
2x &  &  & - & z & = & 1\\
3x & + & y & + & z & = & 0
\end{array}
$$

Write it as an augmented matrix and perform row operations to produce a version in reduced-row echelon form:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{rcrcrc|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{6}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{11}{6}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{4}{3}
\end{array}\right]
$$

The solution set's 3-tuple is:

$$
\left(-\frac{1}{6},\frac{11}{6},-\frac{4}{3}\right)
$$

1. How do I write the solution set as a set of tuples?
2. How do I write the solution set as a set of vectors?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution set can be written as a set of tuples like this:

$$\Big\{\big(-1/6, 11/6, -4/3\big)\Big\}$$

Or as a set of vectors like this:

$$\Bigg\{\begin{bmatrix}-1/6 \\ 11/6 \\ -4/3\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\}$$

In general, when there is only one solution, then the solution set is simply a set with one element. Easy peasy!

Comment: Got it. I wasn't sure because I am used to writing $\mid\rm{variable(s)}\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Oliver Yep, it sounds like you’re most familiar with [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation), but that’s only one way of specifying sets. The other most common way is to simply list out its elements between curly braces, if it has finitely many.

Comment: **UPDATE: This comment is dumb, because there is only one solution.** So, if I were to write it in set builder notation, would there be a $\mid\rm{variable(s)}\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Oliver Lol, that’s kind of a funny question, but sure. You could alternatively write the solution as $$\{(-1/6, 11/6, -4/3)|x\in\mathbb R\}$$. It would be equal to the set specified in my answer, though - the free variable $x$ has no bearing on what is to the left of the |, so it’s extraneous and unnecessary. You could also write $$\{(-1/6, 11/6, -4/3)|x,y,z\in\mathbb R,\space a,b\in\mathbb Q, \space p,q,r\in\mathbb N\}$$ and it would be exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I wish I knew enough about the subject to understand why my question is funny! Or perhaps it was the fact that I was trying to make it more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: @Oliver Yeah, that was why it’s funny. Usually set-builder notation is used for infinite (or at least large) sets, and small sets are usually specified by just listing out their elements.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a problem with there being only one solution rather than infinitely many solutions.  Most people would consider that a good thing!

The "solution set" is the singleton set $\{\left(-\frac{1}{6}, \frac{11}{6}, -\frac{4}{3}\right)\}$.  The "set of vectors" is again a singleton set,$\{-\frac{1}{6}\vec{i}+ \frac{11}{6}\vec{j}- \frac{4}{3}\vec{k}\}$.